# Deleting contacts twice?

Tags: marketing-cloud

When deleting records coming in through MC Connect, do you have to delete them twice? Once from the sync and also from the existing all contacts?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is simple, you need to delete them from Sales/Service Cloud, so they do not appear again in the Synchronized data extensions, and from your Marketing Cloud account using the MC contacts delete process

Comment: NOTE: the Marketing Cloud contact delete process will not delete contacts that appear on non-sending data extensions.

Comment: Would you mind marking this as an answer if it helped resolve your problem?